# How to collect tensor elements by a given segment?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a "segment_collect" (very much like segment_max, but collect into a tensor instead of taking max).

```
t = tf.constant(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
s = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 0])
r = tf.segment_collect(t, s)  # r == [["a", "d"], ["b", "c"]]
```

A naive implementation would be to build the result row by row, in the following pseudo-code:

```
r = []
for i in range(2):
    mask = tf.equal(s, i)
    values = tf.boolean_mask(t, mask)
    r.append(values)
# convert r into a tensor at last
```

but this is not very efficient.

A follow up question is: is there a generic way to do group-by/aggregation for tensors? This would allow many more operations such as segment_size, segment_median, segment_percentile, in addition to segment_{min/max/mean/prod/sum} in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) and [`tf.nn.topk`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k) helpful:

```
tf.gather(t, tf.nn.top_k(-s, k=tf.shape(s)[0]).indices)
```

This works for both TF 1.x and TF 2.0. If needed, reshape the result:

```
tf.reshape(tf.gather(t, tf.nn.top_k(-s, k=tf.shape(s)[0]).indices), shape=(-1, 2))
```

Of course, the reshape assumes that elements are divided into equally sized groups (in this case, two groups).

---

```
tf.keras.backend.eval(tf.gather(t, tf.nn.top_k(-s, k=tf.shape(s)[0]).indices))                                                           
# array([b'a', b'd', b'b', b'c'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is here looking for the answer, tensorflow has you covered:

```
t = tf.constant(["a", "b", "c", "d"]) # input tensor
s = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 0])         # segment ids 
n = tf.unique(s).y.shape[0]           # number of segments

r = tf.dynamic_partition(t, s, n)     # r == [["a", "d"], ["b", "c"]]
```

This also works if the segments contain different numbers of elements.